# WCF RIA and Azure Access Control Servcies

Tags: wcf, azure, ria, wif, acs

I am unable to find any information on how to use Windows **Azure Access Control Service (ACS**) with a Silverlight project using **WCF RIA services**.  I am also unable to get anyone to even discuss the topic on forms etc...    I have even emailed Vittorio Bertocci through his blog orm who is one of Microsoft's WIF guys to no reply.

( at this point i'll take a sarcastic reply just for fun !!)

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest form, you would just piggyback on the browser/website. A simple example is shown here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2009/11/22/updated-ria-and-wif-samples.aspx

and here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2009/11/25/ria-services-and-wif-part-ii.aspx

Where instead of pointing to a fake STS, you would federate with ACS.s No difference.

Comment: I have tried those links, and it appears that nothing happens.
After hitting F5, it just ran as if there was no authentication process at all.  I did notice that it showed my windows USERID.
There was no prompt... 

The source code provided in those links, is dated Mar of 2011.  So there might be a difference between the source code referenced in those links and the directions provided in those links ( 2009 ).
[link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sample-Classifieds-e45e4911)